# How to approach frequent mass updates to SQL database by non-programmer. Should the DB just import from Excel each time?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I am new to database development so any advice is appreciated.

I am tasked with creating a SQL database. This database will store data that is currently on an Excel file. The data in about 50 rows changes every single day (different rows each day).

The person updating the data is a non-programmer and the updating of info needs to be simple and fast.

I'm thinking my client could just update the Excel file, and then this Excel file will upload to the database. Is that feasible? Is there a better way? My client spends enough time just updating the Excel file, so anything that will take a significant amount of extra time for inputing data is not feasible.

Any feedback or ideas is appreciated!

Context: I haven't made any decisions about which SQL DBMS I will use (or maybe I'll use noSQL or Access). I'm still in the how-should-I-approach-this stage of development.

Comment: FYI: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-intro.html

Comment: Woah, cool! Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data all fits in an excel file, there's nothing wrong with that approach.  You need to spend your time thinking about how you want to get the data from excel in to the DB, as you have a ton of options as far as programming languages / tools to do that.

I'm personally a huge fan of Node.js (there are npm modules already existing for reading excel files, writing to mysql, etc, so you would end up writing almost nothing yourself) but you could do it using just about anything.

Do yourself a favor and use a simple database (like MySQL) and don't mess with NoSQL for this.  The amount of data you have is tiny (if it's coming from an excel file) and you really don't need to start worrying about the complexities of NoSQL until you have a a TON of data or data that is changing extremely rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

If the business process is currently updating Excel, then that is probably the best approach.  Modify the Excel file.  A little bit of VBA in the Excel can copy it and store it somewhere for the database.  Schedule a job in the evening, load the data in, and do whatever processing you like.  This is not an unusual architecture.

Given your choice of tools, I would advise you not to use either Access or a NoSQL database, unless you have a particular reason for choosing them.  A free database such as Postgres or SQL Server Express should do a good job meeting your needs.

Comment: Actually I don't see a need for a database at all for just 50 rows of (apparently) non-relational data...

Comment: @RandomSeed . . . 50 records per day is about 18,000 records per year.  There are many operations that are faster in a database than in an Excel spreadsheet.  However, I would guess that the purpose is to share the data among other applications, which is much more easily done in a database than a spreadsheet.

Comment: I understand the 50 rows are to be *updated* rather than *cumulated*, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The Excel file is about 1000 rows * 100 columns.

The DB will be used for other things of course. 

This DB will store products (each row a different product), their prices, and about 98 other attributes. It will be connected to a webpage, a user will login to the webpage, the user will see certain info that is retrieved from the database (depending on who they are), the user can put an order in to buy something, etc etc. No money is exchanged, that is done later. Just a quote of how much something will cost.

Comment: OK I rest my case :) Do use a database.